# Tauri 1.2.3 - Show FileDialog not working

Tags: rust, tauri

I'm trying to build a file dialog in [tauri](https://crates.io/crates/tauri/1.2.3) so that the user can select the directory I'm able to select the directory and it shows up in the console but I'm not able to return the value

```
#[tauri::command]
fn choose_directory() -> Result<String, String> {
    use std::path::PathBuf;
    use tauri::api::dialog::FileDialogBuilder;
    let dialog_result = FileDialogBuilder::new()
        .pick_folder(|folder_path| {
            match folder_path {
                Some(path) => {
                    println!("Selected folder: {:?}", path.to_str());
                    let path_option: Option<PathBuf> = Some(PathBuf::from(path));
                    println!("Selected folder: {:?}", path_option);
                },
                None => println!("User closed the folder dialog."),
            }
        });
        println!("Selected directory: {:?}", dialog_result);
        Err("User canceled dialog".to_string())
}
```

This is the code which I'm using to call invoke the command to open the dialog which works but I'm unable to return the selected path

Answer (score 0):

It will be a bit easier if you make the command async (`async fn`) so that it doesn't run on the main thread. This will allow you to use the [*blocking* dialogs](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/api/dialog/blocking/index.html) which have an easier to use api. Example:

```rs
#[tauri::command]
async fn choose_directory() -> Result<String, String> { // Note the async fn
    use std::path::PathBuf;
    use tauri::api::dialog::blocking::FileDialogBuilder; // Note the updated import

    let dialog_result = FileDialogBuilder::new().pick_folder();
    // dialog_result will be of type Option<PathBuf> now.

    // ...
}
```